# In cx_freeze setup function, what do the name, version, and description keywords actually do?

Tags: python, setuptools, cx-freeze, distutils

When I freeze my code using cx_freeze, I usually include name, version, and description keyword arguments in the setup function because that's what's done in documentation examples. But I can't figure out how these keyword arguments actually affect the output of the setup script. If I ignore or omit these keyword arguments, is it going to cause any problems? Below is the example code from the documentation for reference.

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "guifoo",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My GUI application!",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("guifoo.py", base=base)])
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#additional-meta-data

Answer (score 0):

Hey dear the name is the NAME of the output .exe (application), the description is the description of the app you have made, the description will be shown as the name of the task (application) in the task manager and at last the version is the version of your application..
Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I do see the description show up in the task manager. However the name argument doesn't seem to affect the name of the .exe file. If my script is called hello.py and I pass 'goodbye' into the name argument of the setup function, the resulting .exe is still called hello.exe. I did find that the Executable class has an argument called targetName which will rename the .exe file. Since originally posing this question I have also found that the name argument in the setup function does come into play when I try to make an installer for my scripts (the bdist_msi command in cx-freeze)